# including Modules in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have done a module in lib directory in ruby on rails application
its like

```
module Select  

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end 

 module ClassMethods

    def select_for(object_name, options={})

       #does some operation
      self.send(:include, Selector::InstanceMethods)
    end
  end
```

I called this in a controller like

```
include Selector

  select_for :organization, :submenu => :general
```

but I want to call this in a function
i.e

```
 def select
  #Call the module here 
 end
```

Answer (score 17):

Let's clarify: You have a method defined in a module, and you want that method to be used in an instance method.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include Select

  # You used to call this in the class scope, we're going to move it to
  # An instance scope.
  #
  # select_for :organization, :submenu => :general

  def show # Or any action
    # Now we're using this inside an instance method.
    #
    select_for :organization, :submenu => :general

  end

end
```

I'm going to change your module slightly.  This uses `include` instead of `extend`.  `extend` is for adding class methods, and `include` it for adding instance methods:

```
module Select  

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end 

  module InstanceMethods

    def select_for(object_name, options={})
       # Does some operation
      self.send(:include, Selector::InstanceMethods)
    end

  end

end
```

That will give you an instance method.  If you want both instance and class methods, you just add the ClassMethods module, and use `extend` instead of `include`:

```
module Select  

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include InstanceMethods
      extend  ClassMethods
    end
  end 

  module InstanceMethods

    def select_for(object_name, options={})
       # Does some operation
      self.send(:include, Selector::InstanceMethods)
    end

  end

  module ClassMethods

    def a_class_method
    end

  end

end
```

Does that clear things up?  In your example you defined a module as `Select` but included `Selector` in your controller...I just used `Select` in my code.