# Controller actions in module not being found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

So I'm upgrading a Rails 2 app to Rails 3.2, which is mostly going smooth. However, I have a controller that handles uploading import files, ImportsController, and it uses some actions from a module Importable that provides the same actions to another controller.

```
class ImportsController
   # standard REST stuff
   include Importable
end

module Importable
  def status
    # code to return json has of state machine status
  end
end

# routes
resources :imports do
  member do
    get :status
  end
end
```

Which blows up with: `The action 'status' could not be found for ImportsController`. If I were to say, copy the status action into the ImportsController, everything is fine, however then I'd have to do the same thing in the second controller, so boo duplication. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: I think that the way you defined it, the `status` method is a class method, whereas you want an instance method. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237367/including-modules-in-controller (might help you)

Comment: I actually already tried doing the sub-module method. Since we're calling include, the methods in the module should be treated as class methods, whereas extend would treat it as class methods. Regardless, neither method seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a red herring. With the introduction Rails introduced ActionController::Metal, which defines [def status](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L176)

So I believe it's blowing up because Rails is now trying to use my method to get the HTTP status code and blowing up because it's not returning something that makes sense. Will refactor.